# iOS 11 / 12: How to fetch list of “People Album” from Photos.app

Tags: ios, swift, photo, face

I need to fetch the "People Album" from native photos.app. Is there a way to fetch that result? I tried multiple ways to fetch "People Album", but no success.

Following method I use to fetch Album but I just got top level CollectionList with name "People" but not able to fetch collections inside "People" CollectionList.

```
let peopleFolder = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(
    with: .smartFolder, 
    subtype: .smartFolderFaces, 
    options: nil).firstObject!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fetch request with options and specific predicate:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", "People")
let resultCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(
    .smartAlbum,
    subtype: .albumRegular,
    options: fetchOptions)
```

**NB!** Specify `collectionType` and `suptype` according to your needs.

You can take more information from the sample app [source code provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/Shared_MasterViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Shared_MasterViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_9)

Comment: This does not work for People and Places albums. Either a bug or expected behavior imposed by Apple.